# Maven 3.0.5 installed in Windows 7 but not able to run through command prompt

Tags: maven, path

As per suggestions given in this site i have added the required variables and values as below too but no response

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

M2=%M2_HOME%\bin

M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin

PATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%M2_Home%\bin
```

Please help me

Comment: Install Jenkins... Really easy to get running and provides a console to manage Maven. (For development use the Maven plugin to Eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Your path configuration has a M2_Home instead of M2_HOME. It should be all uppercase

```
%M2_HOME%
```

Also notice, you are specifying bin twice, should

```
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I changed it still not able to run mvn:(

Comment: Please check M2_HOME location and post the updated env variables

Comment: M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5

Comment: As per one user suggestion i have added the M2, M2_HOME variable, Path in User variables. I am able to run mvn from that local folder now

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation multiple times, i.e. configured M2_HOME as user env variable and added it to PATH (system env variable), i.e.

```
PATH=%M2_HOME%\bin; ...
```

However sometimes (randomly) Windows don't resolve variable in path, run "*echo %PATH%*" in your console. In my case I can still see %M2_HOME% there instead of resolved path to maven installation directory. It seems to be a bug in Windows itself, which is present in WinXP and Win7 at least.

I have resolved it as follows:

- Open env variables, change M2_HOME (user one) to correct value. Press OK to save and close window
- Open env variables again, now open PATH (system one) variable details, make sure M2_HOME is there and press OK, i.e. just save without any modification.
- Now, open command line and check "echo %PATH%" - there should be resolved path. Confirm by running "mvn --version".

I know it really sounds like a black magic, but it should work...